# Download CSS with all referenced files

Tags: download, css

Is there a tool that allows me to point to a CSS URL, and recursively download the CSS, as well as all the image and @import urls referenced within it?

For example, if the CSS is at `http://example.com/example.css`

And it has things like `background-image: url('images/bg.gif')`, it should download bg.gif too, and dump it under an images/ subfolder locally. If it has a reference to another stylesheet ex2.css, it should recursively do this on ex2.css as well.

Answer (score 8):

This worked:

```
wget -rHm http://example.com/example.css
```

But it won't work if you have a Windows wget (because GnuWin32's wget is at an older version that doesn't support CSS)

It works on fedora after you upgrade wget to the latest using

```
yum update wget
```

Link:

http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Can_Wget_download_links_found_in_CSS.3F